# Feature file executes successfully but no output is observed

Tags: python, pycharm, bdd

I have been trying to learn BDD with Python and I have written a simple feature file and step implementation for that feature. Step implementation contains simple print statement. After executing the feature file the command prompt reads that the feature file was executed successfull but I cannot see any strings from the step definition file printed. Following are my feature file and step defition

**Feature file (test.feature):**

```
Feature: Sample Feature File
  Scenario: scenario
    Given: precondition
    When: action
    Then: expected
```

***Step definition (test_steps.py):***

```
from behave import *

@given('precondition')
def given(context):
    print('given')

@when('action')
def when(context):
    print('when')

@then('expected')
def close(context):
    print('then')
```

[Image of IDE with the output:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEY1g.png)

- I have tried executing the feature file by passing the absolute path of the feature file as well, i.e behave /test.feature but it didn't work
- I have also tried creating a 'behave.ini' file and have set stderr_capture=False & stdout_capture=False but the result was the same

Comment: pls try to run with these parameters `behave --no-capture --no-color`

Comment: I made a silly mistake, in the feature file I have added colon (:) after the given/when/then keywords which is why it was not executing any step implementation, after removing the colon it worked perfectly fine

Answer (score 0):

I made a silly mistake, in the feature file I have added colon (:) after the given/when/then keywords which is why it was not executing any step implementation, after removing the colon it worked perfectly fine